# JSX not why top one doesnt work but bottom does

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm working on JSX and I a, using ternary operators and I don't get why one version works and the other doesn't. If you could explain that would help a lot.

```
const container = document.getElementById("app");
const root = createRoot(container);

const title = '';
title === '' ? "Click an animal for a fun fact" : title;
const animalFacts = <h1>{title}</h1>;

root.render(animalFacts);
```

```
const container = document.getElementById("app");
const root = createRoot(container);

const title = '';

const animalFacts = <h1>{title === '' ? "Click an animal for a fun fact" : title}</h1>;

root.render(animalFacts);
```

I'm just expecting it to render the title.

Answer (score 2):

Because this expression, as an entire line of code by itself, does nothing:

```
title === '' ? "Click an animal for a fun fact" : title;
```

It resolves to a value, but that value is never assigned to anything.  So this:

```
const title = '';
title === '' ? "Click an animal for a fun fact" : title;
const animalFacts = <h1>{title}</h1>;
```

is logically the same as this:

```
const title = '';
const animalFacts = <h1>{title}</h1>;
```

Contrast that with your other version:

```
const animalFacts = <h1>{title === '' ? "Click an animal for a fun fact" : title}</h1>;
```

in which the result of the expression is used in a JSX structure which is then assigned to the variable `animalFacts`.

---

To use the result of the expression, you can assign it to a variable.  For example:

```
const title = '';
title = title === '' ? "Click an animal for a fun fact" : title;
const animalFacts = <h1>{title}</h1>;
```

Or, since that condition will *always* be true, you could reduce this to:

```
const title = "Click an animal for a fun fact";
const animalFacts = <h1>{title}</h1>;
```

Which, since `title` is never used afterward, could be reduced to:

```
const animalFacts = <h1>Click an animal for a fun fact</h1>;
```